# Working on anti spam bot using discord.py this code runs but doesnt do what its supposed to

Tags: python, discord

Working on an anti spam bot that records author ids to a .txt file ( clearing every 10 seconds) this code runs but I dont see any author names populating in my txt file.

- note I removed the portions of the code with user keys so all I have listed is the code related to the actual anti spam functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import asyncio
import os
import json
import time
import random
import discord
import datetime

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

    ## On Logon ##
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Ready")
        while True:
            print("cleared")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            with open("spam-bank.txt", "r+") as file:
                file.truncate(0)

    async def on_message(message):
    counter = 0
    with open("spam-bank.txt", "r+") as file:
        for lines in file:
            if lines.strip("\n") == str(message.author.id):
                counter+=1
        
        file.writelines(f"{str(message.author.id)}\n")
        if counter > 5:
            await message.guild.ban(message.author, reason="Caught by bot Spamming")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await message.guild.unban(message.author)
            print("Flagged by bot for spamming chat..")
```

Comment: when do you actually write the spammers to your file?

Comment: The indentation of your definition of `on_message` seems weird to me btw. A mistake in copy pasting it over perhaps?

Comment: @lucidbrot Yeah I think thats due to the copy paste

Comment: @lucidbrot I thought writing the spammers to file happened after file.writelines? Sorry about the low level question im new to working with Python

Comment: oh yes, my bad i missed this part. I'll leave this question to someone less tired :p

Comment: @lucidbrot Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing @client.event before the async def on_message